# Java assertion failed- No plan for broadcast hint

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL 1.5.0 ,I have two dataframes ,in which one smaller(less than 3 mb) and the second one is larger, I want to use broadcast join using Spark SQL functions(forceful broadcast hint), but I am getting below error.
pf1 dataframe has volume of 3 MB data

```
df1.join(broadcast(pf1)).show()
```

> java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No plan for BroadcastHint.
>   Unable to find it out solution(because of this my simple join taking
>   morethan 40 min time without broadcast),

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're currently doing a cross join by not specifying a join condition. Add a join condition such as `col("pf1_id") === col("id")`

Then the join should be much faster. If you really do need to do a cross join, please elaborate further with more code, sample data and more extensive stack traces.

Comment: Hi, I have my join condition like below df1. Join (broadcast(df2) , df1. Col(a). Equalto(df2. Col(a)), inner)

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on your question because even giving a broadcast hint wouldn't necessarily have a massive effect on performance. Please specify the size of your DFs as well as more code, maybe the DAG if possible